# Asp.net: Default routing for default files

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am using app.UseDefaultFiles for a welcome page(Default.html). So, what's the default routing for that?

```
app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
   routes.MapRoute(
   name: "default",
   template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Comment: Go back from where ?

Comment: Can`t you use your Index.cshtml to show the content you have inside Default.html ? Or maybe redirect to the Default.html after get in the Home controller, is that an option ?

Comment: Not an option Sr., I'm trying to avoid the Home controller